# Python elif optimization problems

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, if-statement

**How to optimize this code?**

How to optimize this code as short as possible. I am a beginner please help me

out.CONDITIONS:

- arr must be a valid 2D array with valid numbers only.
- data can be : 'column' or 'row'
- value can be : 'min' or 'max' or 'mean' or 'median'
- array must be a valid 2D Array with Integer / Float ONLY

```py
def get_math_value(array, data, value):
    if data == 'row' and value == 'min':
        arr = array
        min_row = list(map(min, arr))
        print(min_row)
    elif data == 'row' and value == 'max':
        arr = array
        max_row = list(map(min, arr))
        print(max_row)
    elif data == 'row' and value == 'mean':
        arr = array
        mean_row = np.mean(arr, axis=1)
        print(mean_row)
    elif data == 'row' and value == 'median':
        arr = array
        median_row = np.median(arr, axis=1)
        print(median_row)
    elif data == 'column' and value == 'min':
        arr = array
        min_column = list(map(min, zip(*arr)))
        print(min_column)
    elif data == 'column' and value == 'max':
        arr = array
        max_column = list(map(max, zip(*arr)))
        print(max_column)
    elif data == 'column' and value == 'mean':
        arr = array
        mean_column = np.mean(arr, axis=0)
        print(mean_column)
    elif data == 'column' and value == 'median':
        arr = array
        median_column = np.median(arr, axis=0)
        print(median_column)
    else:
        print('[]')
```

Comment: What's with all these `arr = array` assignments? you don't need them

Comment: You have a bug in your existing implementation for `row` and `max`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to know is that `numpy` has `min` and `max` functions, so you don't need the `list(map(min, arr))` calls, you can use e.g. `np.min(arr, axis=1)` instead.

With that in mind you could do something like

```
def get_math_value(array, data, value):        
    axis = {'column': 0, 'row': 1}.get(data)
    func = {'mean': np.mean, 
            'median': np.median,
            'min': np.min, 
            'max': np.max}.get(value)
    if axis is None or func is None:
        print('[]')
    else:
        print(func(array, axis=axis))
```

Comment: This works but has some drawbacks: The `axis` and `func` dictionaries have to be re-created each and every time `get_math_value` is called. This can be remedied by making them global variables or as default arguments, but both approaches may be considered as an anti-pattern. Another drawback is that it's not scalable. If OP wants to support a new feature both dictionaries may need to be changed

Comment: Thanks you very much I've learnt alot from this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `np` also for the branches in which you didn't use it, so this becomes very trivial to solve with [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). You also don't need all these `arr = array` assignments.

Your entire function can become:

```
def get_math_value(array, data, value):
     # TODO maybe check explicitly for 'row'/'column', otherwise display an error
    axis = 1 if data == 'row' else 0
    try:
        print(list(getattr(np, value)(array, axis)))
    except AttributeError:
        print('[]')
```

Then

```
get_math_value([[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 6]], 'row', 'min')
get_math_value([[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 6]], 'row', 'max')
get_math_value([[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 6]], 'column', 'min')
get_math_value([[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 6]], 'row', 'median')
get_math_value([[1, 2, 3], [5, 4, 6]], 'row', 'non_existing_numpy_method')
```

Outputs

```
[1, 4]
[3, 6]
[1, 2, 3]
[2.0, 5.0]
[]
```

Comment: that `getattr` might be a bit "magical" considering the OP is a self proclaimed "beginner".  splitting it out onto its own line might help them understand what's going on

Comment: Thanks you very much I've learnt alot from this